# Dynamic symbols in Clojure Macro/Special Form

Tags: clojure, macros, symbols, special-form

I have a question regarding how to define functions/macros which call other macros or special forms but where one of the symbols passed in needs to be dynamic.

The simplest version of this question is described below:

We can define variables using `def`

```
(def x 0)
```

But what if we wanted the name `x` to be determined programmatically so that we could do the equivalent of?

```
(let [a 'b]
  (our-def a 3)) => user/b
```

We could try to define a function

```
(defn defn2 [sym val]
  (def sym val))
```

However it does not do what we want

```
(def2 'y 1)   => #'user/sym
```

At first it seems like a macro works (even though it seems like it would be unnecessary)

```
(defmacro def3 [sym val]
  `(def ~sym ~val))

(def3 z 2) => user/z
```

but it is just superficial, because we're really right back where we started with regular def.

```
(let [a 'b]
  (def3 a 3)) => user/a
```

I can do it if I use `eval`, but it doesn't seem like `eval` should be necessary

```
(defn def4 [sym val]
  (eval `(def ~sym ~val)))

(let [a 'b]
  (def4 a 4)) => user/b
```

If there are other built-in commands that could achieve this particular example, they are not really what I am looking for since `def` is just to show a particular example. There are macros more complicated than `def` that I might want to call and not have to worry about how they were internally implemented.

Answer (score 1):

First: The right way to do this is to use macro that starts with `def...` since this is the way people have been doing defs and is of little surprise to the user.

To answer you question: Use [intern](http://clojure.org/vars):

```
(def foo 'bar)
(intern *ns* foo :hi)
(pr bar) ;; => :hi
(intern *ns* foo :hi2)
(pr bar) ;; => :hi2
```

If you want to use macros do this:

```
(def z 'aa)
(defmacro def3 [sym val]
  `(def ~(eval sym) ~val))
(def3 z 2)
(pr aa) ;; => 2
```

Comment: Hi Andre, Thank you for taking the time to answer, but as the question points out, I'm looking to know if there is a way to do this using `def` and not with other functions such as `intern` because there are many other similar macros (`defn`, `defmacro`, `defmulti`, `defmethod`, `defrecord`,`clojure.core.logic/defne`) and while most of these have pretty small bodies which could probably be re-implemented as a function, they or other library macros could have defined them in one enormous macro like the `for` macro, or the function they are defined in terms of might be part of a 'private' API.

Comment: `(partial intern *ns*)` seems to be exactly the function you tried to define in the question.   My understanding now is that your question really has nothing to do with `def` per se.  What you're asking is how to pass an evaluated argument to a macro that normally wouldn't evaluate it.  Is that correct?

Comment: btw I don't think it would be hard to define a simple function version of  `defn` using the above function version of `def`.  The others may be more difficult.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Maybe this is an XY problem: Are you just playing around for fun or are you actually trying to use this for something specific? If yes, what? Regarding macros: They're evaluated by the compiler, so if you can get the actual symbol during your compile phase then there is nothing wrong with emitting a `(def ~(eval sym) ~val)`.

Comment: Hi Mars and Andre, It started out as something specific (like Mars mentioned it wasn't `def` in that particular case) but I solved that problem by using `eval` around the form and from that point on it became 'I really want to know if this generally can be solved without `eval` or reverse engineering the macro I wish to call in order to use `intern`'.